# Go to different main table from same field AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have a InvoiceAccount field in table. And another field in this table is PackingSlipAXType. If PackingSlipAXType is Sales, InvoiceAccount field value is customer account. If type is PurchReturn, InvoiceAccount field value is vendor account.

When value is customer account, when right click and go to main table i want to go Customer 
and
When value is vendor account, when right click and go to main table i want to go vendor.

How can i do this in same field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two primary ways. One is code and the other is using native `MorphX` and `Conditional Table Relations`. Code gives you more flexibility, but conditional table relations are simpler and "just work".

### Conditional Table Relations

Using conditional table relations. I created a new table and `AccountNum` would represent a customer or vendor account, and the base enum `SalesPurch` is used to indicate if it is a Customer Account (Sales) or a Vendor Account (Purch). Similar to your setup.

[image]

- See conditional table relations - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/conditional-table-relations
- See [here for more info too](https://dynamicsaxinsight.wordpress.com/2014/01/23/conditional-relations-with-field-fixed-and-related-field-fixed/#:~:text=AX%202012%3A%20Conditional%20Relations%20with%20Field%20Fixed%20and%20Related%20Field%20Fixed,-muhammadanaskhan%20Development%20(AX&text=Conditional%20relations%20are%20used%20to,in%20a%20table%20relation%20as%3A&text=Related%20Field%20Fixed,-Consider%20a%20scenario).

### Custom JumpRef & Lookup

You will likely want both a `jumpRef` and a `lookup` to both go to the correct main table and lookup the correct values.. This is code, but you have all the flexibility in the world...but may not need it.

- Jumpref - https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/b/faisalfareedaxlibrary/posts/ax-2012-how-to-use-jumpref-method
- Lookup - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/how-to-add-a-lookup-form-to-a-control
- Jumpref example at `\Data Dictionary\Tables\TmpCostAllocationBase_RU\Methods\jumpRefAgreement`
- Lookup example at `\Data Dictionary\Tables\TmpCostAllocationBase_RU\Methods\lookupAgreement`

Comment: I think you mean custom `JumpRef ` which is responsible for "go to main table"  instead of custom `lookup`

Comment: @AliaksandrMaksimau oops you're right. I just skimmed the question. I'll edit.